# Cannot assign complex data into array variable in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have implement a method to retrieve data from HTTP request and it's working fine and return complex data list.

[image]

But my concern is when I assign that returned list to variable,It's not assigning.So I can't even loop that variable because it's **undefined** in .ts file.

[image]

**This is my Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatUserVM } from '../shared/models';
import { UserService } from '../shared/service/user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-footer',
  templateUrl: './chat-footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-footer.component.css'],
})
export class ChatFooterComponent implements OnInit { 
  friendList: ChatUserVM[] = []; 

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllFriendsFromDatabase();
  }

  getAllFriendsFromDatabase() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.friendList = data;
        console.log('DB usersss ---> ' + this.friendList);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my HTTP service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ChatUserVM} from "../models";

@Injectable()

export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {      
    return this.http.get<ChatUserVM[]>('https://localhost:44346/api/chat/GetAllUsers');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This behavior makes no sense.  Are you sure it's not just a glitch with your debugger not being on the line it thinks it's on?  What do you see if you `console.log` both `data` and `this.friendList`?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Yes data displaying if I use console.log but can't see in debugger . But problem is, If I need to access that **this.friendList** in other place suck as inside other function it shows as **undefined**

Comment: This may be the classic problem of trying to use the result of an asynchronous operation before it completes.  Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue have been solved.. :D  It worked after I changed like this.

```js
 getAllFriendsFromDatabase() {
    var self = this;
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        self._moderatorList = data as ChatUserVM[];
        console.log('DB usersss ---> ' + self._moderatorList);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that in typescript, as that's kind of what it does when it generates the javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a debugger bug. It gets confused by **this**. If you were to debug the generated javascript you'd get the right values, but in your case, the debugger resolves **this** to window, which most likely won't have a friendList field or property resulting in displaying "undefined". 
And **this** is why I never debug typescript code, but the generated javascript instead. Not saying you shouldn't, just be aware of that caveat.